# After more than 10 files in S3 bucket start deleting oldest- AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a folder I copied from C: to my S3 bucket. I am looking to now filter the bucket so it is not constantly filling up with Tableau files. I'd like to keep the latest/most recent 10 and delete/rm the rest that are older.

```
bucket="s3://tableauserver_GO/Servbackups/" --recursive --include "*.tsbak"
```

I'm trying to run a `aws s3 rm` in powershell that uses the `datestamp` on the files to keep the 10 most recent and deletes the rest.  The `aws` documentation shows recursive examples and shows how to exclude and include, but I'm lost.

Comment: You can't do this with the awscli - the 'aws s3 rm' command does not provide any way to filter for "all but the 10 latest objects" or even "all objects older than X". If you want to do the latter, you can use a lifecycle policy. If you want to do the former, I think you're going to have to write some code.

Comment: Id also like to note. I am doing this in powershell

Comment: Your example uses the awscli, which you can run in a Linux shell, Windows cmd shell, or PowerShell. But that's not too important. Deleting "all but the 10 latest objects" is going to require you to list all of the objects using the awscli or, if you prefer, the AWS Tools for PowerShell, identify the objects to delete, and then delete them. Alternatively, if acceptable, you could use AWS S3 Inventory to identify the objects but that inventory is only created once per day.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up putting a lifecycle rule on it.  Im newer at this stuff so I appreciate it.  On to error handling and researching Tricatching!